# Бинарный лог MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, логирование, mariadb

Не могу включить бинарный лог. Нашел в интернете что бинарный лог можно включить раскомментировав строку `log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log` в  конфигурационном файле `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Но там нету такого пункта.

Вот что в этом конфигурационном файле:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Зашел в папки `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` и `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` там в файлах `mysqld.cnf` и `50-server.cnf` нашел и раскомментировал эти строки но всё же лог не ведется.

> **P.S.** Операционная система: **Ubuntu 16.04**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M
#binlog_do_db = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db = include_database_name
```

Далее рестарт СУБД:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Убеждаемся, что бинарный лог создался и начинает расти в размере:

```
ls -al /var/log/mysql
total 16K
drwxr-s--- 2 mysql adm 4.0K 2010-05-17 04:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K 2010-05-16 06:25 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql adm 471 2010-05-17 04:41 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql adm 32 2010-05-17 04:40 mysql-bin.index
```

Расскоментрируйте эту строку `log-bin=mysql-bin`